# How to rewrite a url using Htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I would like help in rewriting a url eg domain.com/home to domain.com/folder/ using Htaccess. I have a folder named /var/www/home, accessing it I would type the Ip address followed by folder name eg 127.0.0.1/home. I want to access the same directory in the url by typing eg 127.0.0.1/folder. and also when the user types 127.0.0.1/home he/she is directed to 127.0.0.1/folder. I believe I can use Htaccess but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these 2 rules in your site root `/var/www/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+home(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /folder%1 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^folder(/.*)?$ home$1 [L,NC]
```